# In MongoDB how to update a document with different values conditionally based on another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have to read multiple documents. Loop over them; If a document has images I make the status 'X' and if it doesnt I make it 'Y'. 
I have implemented it like this

```
const studies = await StudyModel.find({ status: 'uploading' });
studies.forEach(s => {
  // Some more synchronous operations
  const status = s.images ? 'X' : 'Y';
  // non blocking update study call
  StudyModel.Update({_id: study._id}, { status: studyStatus });
})
```

Now what if after reading studies and before updating, user adds images in a study. Then there are images in the study in db and status should be 'X' but code will make it 'Y' as it doesnt see the new images.
It is a rare case yet has happened a few times.

What I am looking for is a way to conditionally check images in db and make update based on that. Something of this sort.

```
StudyModel.Update({_id: id}, {$set: {status: {"$cond": {if: '$images', then: 'X', else: 'Y' } } } } )
```

Is there a way to do this? And how can such a problem be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $exist but there are two commands.

```
    // image is exist
    db.collection.updateMany(
      { status: 'uploading', image: { $exists: true } },
      { $set: { images: X} },
      {
        upsert: true,
      }
    )

  // image is not exist  
    db.collection.updateMany(
      { status: 'uploading', image: { $exists: false } },
      { $set: { images: Y} },
      {
        upsert: true,
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in Mongo version 4.2+ which allows using of [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) in the update document and the various `update` collection methods.

Version 4.2 introduced the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) pipeline stage operator.

```
db.collection.update(
    { },
    [
        {$set: {status: {"$cond": {if: '$images', then: 'X', else: 'Y' } } } },
    ],
    { multi: true }
)
```

On earlier Mongo versions i'm afraid you'll have to use some workaround like splitting the update into 2 separate updates.